# Duplicate results with SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates

```
SELECT `groups`.`name`, `groups`.`id`
FROM `groups`
JOIN `group_members`
    ON (`group_members`.`user_id` = `groups`.`user_id`)
WHERE `groups`.`user_id` = '33'
ORDER BY `groups`.`id`
```

I need to get group's ID and group's name for every group he is member in. But results can't duplicate!

My query returns a lot of duplicate entries.

In `groups` are stored all groups that do exists (`name`, `description` etc.). In `group_members` are stored all users that are members of some group (`user_id`, `group_id` etc.).

How to modify this query to get not-duplicate, but correct results? Thanks in advice!

**Edit:**

In `groups` there are no `user_id`. All member of the group are stored in `group_members` table. I need to get all groups (group's ID and name) where user is member.

Comment: Why does groups have a user_id? Is it the owner?

Comment: @cularis : it is not GROUP table representing the groups, it is GROUP_MEMBERS table representing connection between mamber and group...

Comment: @Daniel thats why its illogical to join on groups.user_id?

Comment: The way I see it groups contains all groups and group_members has the members of all groups. If you want all groups a user is a member of, you have to join groups with group_members on id/group_id and then use where on group_members.user_id.

Comment: @cularis I guess he confused tables/fields on join and in where clause...

Comment: You said your query was returning duplicate rows, but then you said `groups` has no `user_id` on it. If that's the case, your query doesn't return duplicate rows, it *fails*, because it has `WHERE groups.user_id = 33`. Please post the actual table structure and the actual query you're having trouble with, otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Hmmm... gonna take a look why does `groups` has `user_id`. Anyway, @cularis solved this mystery! Thanks. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know all groups of one user, you have to join on the `group_members.group_id` and edit the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT `groups`.`name`, `groups`.`id`
FROM `groups`
JOIN `group_members`
    ON (`group_members`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`)
WHERE `group_members`.`user_id` = '33'
ORDER BY `groups`.`id`
```

Comment: I think this is the solution. OP has joined on the wrong fields.

Comment: this works but it's good to use EXISTS to optimize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787927/duplicate-results-with-sql-join/6788056#6788056

Answer (score 1):

First, your query states:

```
`groups`.`user_id` = '33'
```

This seems incorrect because why would there be a user in the group-table?

Regarding the question. You are probably getting duplicates because a user can exist in more than one group. So, in other words if you only want exactly one group per user then it depends on which group you'd like to see. It could be the minimum group id, maximum or pretty much whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused some fields i guess, here you go:

```
SELECT `groups`.`name`, `groups`.`id` 
FROM `groups` 
JOIN `group_members`     
ON `group_members`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id` 
WHERE `groups_members`.`user_id` = '33' 
ORDER BY `groups`.`id
```

Comment: I actually made some mistake because of a wrong assumption, he needs a join from groups to groups_members...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.name, g.id
FROM groups g
where EXISTS (
  select 'x'
  from group_members gm
  where g.id = gm.group_id
    and gm.user_id = '33'
)
ORDER BY g.id
```